# How to show just the legend in R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I want to create a legend to depict what different colors mean. Like the image below:
[image]

I'm able to achieve this by passing Null values to plot but the plot takes up a lot more white space around it. (Screenshot attached below).
Is there any other way using which I can just show legend.
[image]
Here's the piece of code I used.

```
plot(NULL ,xaxt='n',yaxt='n',bty='n',ylab='',xlab='', xlim=0:1, ylim=0:1)
legend("topright", horiz = T, legend =c('Good', 'Bad', 'Poor'), pch=15, pt.cex=5, cex=1.5, bty='n', col = c('#3d9970','#ff851b', '#dd4b39'))
```

Comment: do you have to create a plot or can you save an image and call that

Comment: @Mike No I don't want to use an image for this. I was hoping to accomplish it using legend or some HTML way to get the same look and feel (like we have in legend)

Answer (score 1):

You've already created it, so why create it again? If you want to use this image, but without all the added whitespace, you can trim out the whitespace using the `magick` package.

```
library(magick)

fig <- image_graph(width = 600, height = 400, res = 96)
plot(NULL ,xaxt='n',yaxt='n',bty='n',ylab='',xlab='', xlim=0:1, ylim=0:1)
legend("topright", horiz = T, legend =c('Good', 'Bad', 'Poor'), 
       pch=15, pt.cex=5, cex=1.5, bty='n', col = c('#3d9970','#ff851b', '#dd4b39'))
dev.off()

figT <- image_trim(fig)
```

[image]

---

---

#### Update

You asked if this could be done with HTML tags. This is an example of strictly HTML with inline CSS. (Ideally, CSS isn't inline.)

```html
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
  <div style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #3d9970;"></div>
  <p style="font-size: 20px; padding:0px 8px 0px 4px;">Good</p>
  <div style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #ff851b;"></div>
  <p style="font-size: 20px; padding:0px 8px 0px 4px;">Bad</p>
  <div style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background: #dd4b39;"></div>
  <p style="font-size: 20px; padding:0px 8px 0px 4px;">Poor</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I was trying to accomplish it without using image. Is there any other way possible using legend or HTML tags?

Comment: It can be done with HTML tags, as well. I've added that to my answer.